# Wrong results with $or in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I created the collection schools in MongoDB (v3.4) with a validator:

```
{$and: [
            {a: {$or: [{$lt: 5}, {$gt: 10}]}},
            {b: {$or: [{$lt: 20}, {$gt: 30}]}}
        ]}
```

I also tried with implicit $and:

```
{
     a: {$or: [{$lt: 5}, {$gt: 10}]},
     b: {$or: [{$lt: 20}, {$gt: 30}]}
}
```

However, both these validators accept the following document:

```
db.schools.insert({
    a: 7,
    b: 25
});
```

I met the similar problem when trying the following validators:

```
 // Validator using explicit $and
    {$and: [
        a: {$or: [{$type: 'int'}, {$type: 'string'}]},
        b: {$or: [{$type: 'int'}, {$type: 'string'}]},
    ]} 
 // Validator using implicit $and
    {
        a: {$or: [{$type: 'int'}, {$type: 'string'}]},
        b: {$or: [{$type: 'int'}, {$type: 'string'}]},
    } 
 //------------------------------------
 //Insert a document into schools:
  db.schools.insert({
    a: new Date(),
    b: new Date()
});
```

Can anyone explain why these validators cannot exclude the documents?

Comment: `$or` is a very **specific** operator, and can only be applied to a **specific** "key" property. You actually mean `.find({ "$and": [ { "$or": [{ "a": { "$type": "string" } },{ "a": { "$type": "int" } } ] }, { "$or": [{ "b": { "$type": "string" } }, { "b": { "$type": "int" } } ]} ] })`. You cannot use `$or` without a "full" statement that actually names the "key" to apply to.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Your query works perfectly. I read MongoDB documentation but it just describes that both $and and $or can applied to expressions generally. Can I ask one more question? How can I know which operators can be only applied to specific 'key' property? Because as in your above code, $and can be applied directly to operator $or. How's about other logical operators ($not, $nor)?